# Generic way of identifying native functions in Node js

Tags: node.js

Is there any general way to identify native functions in Node.js?

For example, to test for a native function in the browser, I would use this -

`function isNative(fn) {
    return (/{\s*[native code]\s*}/).test('' + fn);
}`

Is there something similar we can use for detecting native Node.js functions like fs.readFile and so on?

I guess one way would be to check to cache the functions available in the GLOBAL variable before the start of the program, is there a more elegant way though?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that node's builtin functions are technically non-native (for v8). The only way is to check function origin file name:

```
var FunctionOrigin = require('function-origin');
var natives = process.binding('natives');

function isNative(fn) {
  var file = FunctionOrigin(fn).file;
  var noExt = file.slice(0, file.length - 3);

  return natives.hasOwnProperty(noExt);
}


function Test(){}


console.log(isNative(require('fs').readFile));
console.log(isNative(Test));
```

Comment: It works fine, except JavaScript 'native' functions e.g. JSON.stringify() or setInterval(). Unfortunately, I cannot install 'function-origin' module in Windows, only on Mac, but think it a problem of Node.js setup.

Comment: for `JSON.stringify` you can check `toString`, it is really native. for `setInterval` this should work

Comment: Sorry, for setInterval, setTimeout - it does not. For require - is Ok.

Answer (score -1):

Another possible (and definitly 'not elegant') approach for the solution: to check all standard Node.js packages with their function names (I prepared the list of standard modules for v0.10.35 from Node.js github `/lib` folder according Node's [recomendations on Core Modules](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_core_modules)).

Unfortunately, Node.js does not save an information about loaded core modules in `require.cache`, so it is impossible to detect them by this way.

The function testNative() detects almost all 'native' functions, except require() (and probably some other functions written on JavaScript and located outside Node.js modules).

Comments:

1. I fill native_fns array inside the function testNative(). If it is slow, you can extract this part outside the function.
2. The function uses eval() for detection of loaded modules, so you need to follow the proper naming rule.

So, the test function works only if you always use standard variable names for library variables:

```
var fs = require('fs');    // good
var myfs = require('fs');  // bad
```

***UPDATE:*** This ugly part can be replaced with analysis of **process.moduleList** .

The code:

```
function testNative(fn) { 
    if(!!fn.toString().match(/{\s*\[native code\]\s*}/)) return true;

    var std_modules = ['assert','buffer','child_process','cluster','console','constants',
       'crypto','dgram','dns','domain','events','freelist','fs','http','https','module',
       'net','os','path','punycode','querystring','readline','repl','smalloc','stream',
       'string_decoder','sys','timers','tls','tracing','tty','url','util','vm','zlib',
        'Math','JSON'];

    var native_fns = [];
    for(var i=0; i<std_modules.length;i++) {
        try {
           var module = eval(std_modules[i]);
            native_fns.push(module);
            if(module) {
                for(var k in module) {
                     native_fns.push(module[k]);
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {}
    }

    return  native_fns.indexOf(fn) > -1;
}

// Test
function foo() {return 1};
var fs = require('fs');

console.log(testNative(fs.readFile));    // true
console.log(testNative(foo));            // false
console.log(testNative(JSON.stringify)); // true
```

Comment: Using the standard module names always is too strong an assumption to make I think